# DPDA for $\{1^ky \mid \text{$y\in \{0,1\}^*$ with $|y|_1 \le k$ and $k \in \mathbb N: k\ge1$}\}$

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

I need some help with the following task:

I have to construct a DPDA for $\{1^ky \mid \text{$y\in \{0,1\}^*$ with $|y|_1 \le k$ and $k \in \mathbb N: k\ge1$}\}$.

How can I recognize that the new substring $y$ begins? For example: $w=zy$, where
$z = 1111$ and $y = 1001$.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to verify whether the string is of the form $1^ky$ with $y\in \{0,1\}^*$ and $|y|_1\le k$ you want to determine whether a symbol $1$ in the prefix belongs to the $1^k$ part, or starts $y$.

Now imagine $1^k \cdot 1y$ is of the correct form, i.e., $|1y|_1 \le k$, then certainly $1^{k+1}\cdot y$ is also correct, as $|y|_1< |1y|_1 \le k < (k+1)$.

So, keep reading $1$'s while possible.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I have to push the first $1's$ until the first $0$ is under the head. From that point on I have to pop $1's$ until the stack is empty and go in an accept state iff the string w is empty. Otherwise I do not accept w. Is this correct?

Comment: That seems to be it.

Answer (score 2):

It is clear $y$ starts with $0$; so all you have to do is to push $1$ on the stack as long as there is no $0$, afterwards delete a $1$ from the stack for each $1$ in the input. This will jam if there are too many $1$s in $y$, you can accept by final state if you reach the end of the input.